# why search results are showing blank space into enterprise search results in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: search, sharepoint, enterprise

I am getting blank space in search result if i search anything in search box. but if i search only people then result are looking fine. I have tried many way to resolve it but couldn't resolve this issue as i don't have strong knowledge of Sharepoint . please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: "Results for hr" section is blank but result are coming properly under it.]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just people result Type and one display template which is not suitable for any result except for people result. For the different type of search result you need to describe new result type and new display template which is needed for showing the result. Otherwise you have to modify the the result type and display template to handle all result type.

In the display template you choose the managed property to show. In this case, the managed properties are suitable for the people but not for others. for example, In the current display template your first managed property is "PersonName". The results which are not related people dont have "PersonName" data. So, It shows empty.

You can see the result types by url below.

rootsite/_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol

In the results type -click edit- you can see which display templated is used.